# Add an Empty Array to An Array with Existing Values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently receiving this error with the following code:

TypeError: data.data.trek.days[current_day] is undefined

The problem I am having is that I need to add the current_day along with an empty places array to the existing array structure if one hasn't been previously provided.  How can I do this?

```
data.data.trek.days[current_day].places.push({
    "url": url,
    "img_src": img_src,
    "title": title,
    "time_going_hour": time_going_hour,
    "time_going_minutes": time_going_minutes,
    "duration": "3600",
    "id": id,
    "type": type,
    "city_id": city_id
});
```

Comment: You're trying to see if `data.data.trek.days[current_day].places` has length?

Comment: UPDATE: When I try to do: data.data.trek.days.push(current_day);

I get this error: TypeError: data.data.trek.days.push is not a function

Comment: is days even defined? print out via `console.log(data.data.trek)` and see if days exist as a member

Comment: No, I want to add the current_day as a key in the days array and add an empty places array as a value of that key.

Comment: Yes, days is defined and returns:

1
 Object { places=[3]}
 
2
 Object { places=[4]}

Comment: @jahroy that would probably work, but for example data.data.trek.days[4] isn't defined yet.

Comment: This works: (data.data.trek.days[current_day] = (data.data.trek.days[current_day] || {places:[]} )).places.push({

Answer (score 1):

From your comment you seem to want this:

```
data.data.trek.days = data.data.trek.days || {};
data.data.trek.days[current_day] = data.data.trek.days[current_day] || {};
data.data.trek.days[current_day].places = data.data.trek.days[current_day].places || [];
data.data.trek.days[current_day].places.push({ ... });
```